# automate navigation of a JavaScript powered website

Tags: javascript, python, web

I need to automate navigation around a JavaScript powered website in Python so I can scrape some content. I came across [Chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/quickstart.html), which is a FireFox extension that gives me a programming interface to the browser.

Do you know of other solutions?

Comment: +1 for introducing me to Chickenfoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 3):

[WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) has several extensions/compatible replacements to handle JavaScript: WWW::Mechanize::FireFox, WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::JavaScript/WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript, Mozilla::Mechanize, Gtk2::WebKit::Mechanize, Win32::IE::Mechanize.

Comment: is there a Python equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

You can automate Internet Explorer pretty easily from either javascript (.js files) or any other language that can use COM (c#, perl etc)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28VS.85%29.aspx

Simple example in vbscript:

```
Dim objIE
Dim objWebForm
Dim objDoc
dim leCount
dim objElement
dim objElementCollection
dim leIndex

Set objIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.AddressBar = true
objIE.Visible = true

Sub WaitForLoad (objIE)
  Do While objIE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep(1000)
  Loop
  WScript.Sleep(500)
End Sub

objIE.Navigate("http://www.softtesting.org/")
WaitForLoad(objIE)
set objDoc = objIE.document

Set objElementCollection = objDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
leCount = objElementCollection.length
For leIndex = 0 To leCount-1
    Set objElement =  objElementCollection(leIndex)
    If (("http://www.softtesting.org/forum/")=objElement.href) Then
        objElement.Click()
    End If
Next
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/6c47aaec-6beb-4b21-95b2-95186f5bb4a5

Comment: unfortunately I'm on linux...looks neat though

Answer (score 0):

check http://watin.org/
it's like chickenfoot, but it also support ie. And it's free.