# Play music from Python

Tags: python, selenium, grooveshark

Does anybody know if it's possible to press the play button on a music website using Python? What I'm trying to do is make an alarm clock script that plays a random playlist on a music site.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698285/automate-navigation-of-a-javascript-powered-website) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512642/documentation-examples-of-using-selenium-python-to-navigate-a-website) are similar questions (I think), although I don't know if what I'm using applies to this. I'm trying to use Grooveshark.

Comment: Would it make sense to download the webpage and simulate pressing the play button?

Answer (score 0):

The first linked question's answer, to use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), is probably your best bet. You can write your code in Python, and any other way of interfacing with a website as complex as Grooveshark will probably not be easy. There *is* an API (http://developers.grooveshark.com) but for what you want Selenium is probably the easiest approach.

Answer (score -1):

just use tkinter button widget and use pygame musicplayer, it works very well.